# Will Kafka without Zookeeper still require at least n nodes running in n*2+1 nodes cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

In the traditional Kafka+Zookeeper setup x-node Kafka cluster is running alongside y-node Zookeper ensemble. Zookeeper requires more than a half of the nodes to be up, in order to be fully functioning, as explain for example here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/zookeeper/deployment.html#multi-node-setup

The new Kafka setup won't require Zookeeper cluster anymore. Does it mean that now for Kafka cluster to be functioning, more than half of the cluster brokers will have to be running? If not, will there be any other requirements in relation to the minimum number of brokers still running?

As a background: I'm considering running Kafka cluster across two availability zones, but it doesn't seem to be practical. If one of the zones goes down, there won't be Zookeeper quorum anymore. I'm wondering if in the future this kind of setup will be more practical.

Comment: You should have 3 AZ's for maintaining quorum, but to answer the question, you'd have to consult KIP-500 docs or the Raft protocol to know how quorum is maintained.

Comment: I found this documentation https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/kraft/README.md, and as far as I understand with the new setup you designate some Kafka nodes as controllers, and then the same rules apply as for Zookeeper - so with 3 controllers, at least 2 have to be working, with 5, at least 3 and so on. Would be nice to get confirmation I understand it right though

Comment: That's the only document I'm aware of, outside of the KIP-500 page that I mentioned. But your understanding seems accurate to me. Overall, if you read the page, it's not planned to be able to upgrade from the current KRaft implementation to any eventual "production ready" version, so I personally wouldn't suggest using that as your "daily driver" for a new installation anyway